# How to get Qt 5.8 working with OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I am trying to get Qt 5.8 working with OpenSSL on Windows, but every time I get a step forward I hit another bigger object.

**Edit/Update:** This error occurs only in debug mode!

Here is my setup so far:

- Installed Qt 5.8
- Downloaded and compiled version of OpenSSL
- Transfer the small test project to MSVS2015
- Copied dll files (libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll) to the application Directory
- SSL connection is now working fine

But here is the problem:
Every time I had a connection open whether with SSL or not I get an error by quitting the application. 
Exception thrown at (ntdll.dll).

[image: Error Message, Call Stack, ...]

I tested my code with the Visual Leak Detector because I thought it was a Memory issue, but it does not solve my Problem.
I rally have no clue where I should start anymore...

[Here is a small example in Qt Creator 4.2.1 which doesn't work either](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RkTj0UzvBAUWJjSi1KUFEzVjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Here is my Code (it works fine with http, when I delete the OpenSSL dll's):

```
void InfoGatherer::getInfo(QString name)
{
    // TODO: Search for the name and select right page
    QUrl url = QUrl(name);
    data.clear();

    QNetworkRequest *request = new QNetworkRequest(url);
    request->setRawHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);

    if (name.startsWith("https"))
    {
        QSslConfiguration sslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
        sslConfiguration.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2OrLater);
        request->setSslConfiguration(sslConfiguration);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Try to get https
    }

    reply = webCtrl->get(*request);

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(onReadyRead()));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onReplyFinished()));

    // Mem leaks (Visual Leak Detector)
    if(!name.startsWith("https"))
        webCtrl->deleteResource(*request);

    delete request;
}

void InfoGatherer::onReadyRead()
{
    data.append(reply->readAll());
}

void InfoGatherer::slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)
{
    // TODO
    qWarning() << "ErrorNo: " << reply->error() << "for url: " << reply->url().toString();
    qDebug() << "Request failed, " << reply->errorString();
    qDebug() << "Headers:" << reply->rawHeaderList() << "content:" << reply->readAll();
}

void InfoGatherer::onReplyFinished()
{
    QString html = QString(data);

    emit got_webpage(&html);
}
```

Qt detects the OpenSSL library correctly:

```
qDebug() << "Support SSL:  " << QSslSocket::supportsSsl()
        << "\nLib Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionNumber()
        << "\nLib Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()
        << "\nLib Build Version Number: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionNumber()
        << "\nLib Build Version String: " << QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
```

- Support SSL:   true
- Lib Version Number:  268443791
- Lib Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016"
- Lib Build Version Number:  268443791
- Lib Build Version String:  "OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Build all dll's from OpenSSL again and dont forget to build the debug dll's.

[Here](http://developer.covenanteyes.com/building-openssl-for-visual-studio/) is a very good link how to build the dll's. Build the 64 Bit normal and debug Version!

From the Footnotes use:
 - nmake -f ms\nt**dll**.mak (install) to get the dll's

And **don't** rename dll's to libeay64.dll and ssleay64.dll.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try the prebuild Windows binaries for OpenSSL from [slproweb.com](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Also it seems that **Qt 5.8** needs **OpenSSL v1.0.2** to work properly.

Comment: Please read the last 5 points in my question. I work allready with OpenSSL 1.0.2h!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Just a local variable for request.

```
QUrl imageUrl = QUrl (link);
QNetworkRequest request (imageUrl);

/* SSL Configuration */
QSslConfiguration sslConfiguration = request.sslConfiguration();
sslConfiguration.setPeerVerifyMode (QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
sslConfiguration.setProtocol (QSsl::AnyProtocol);
request.setSslConfiguration (sslConfiguration);
networkAccessMgr->get (request);
```

- Verify Peer Mode: `QSslSocket::VerifyNone`
- Protocol: `QSsl::AnyProtocol`

Comment: Nope this doesn't fix anything. Testet it in my code and created a new little project only for testing a even smaller example. [Here is my small project in Qt Creator 4.2.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RkTj0UzvBAUWJjSi1KUFEzVjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yea same for me, but then when I close the application -> "DebugForOnlineTest.exe doesn't work anymore, would you like to search for the problem?"

Comment: Interesting. It seems the example application works fine in release mode but not in debug mode.